# eclipselink - query field with abstract getter from base class that implemented in derived classes

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, abstract

I define a named query on class "abstractClass" that use field from base class.
This field has abstacrt getter on the base class, and the implementations of the getter are on several derived classes.

When eclipselink trying to complie this query, I have this exception:

Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345):           org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select c from abstractClass c where c.flag = false and c.id in (1,2,3) order by c.id].
**The state field path 'c.id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.**

My classes and query:

```
public abstract abstractBaseClass
{
    private int id;
    private boolean flag;

    public abstract int getId();
    public boolean getFlag(){return flag};
}

@NamedQuery(name="query", 
    query="select c from abstractClass c where c.flag = false and c.id in (1,2,3) order by c.id") 
public abstract abstractClass extends abstractBaseClass
{

}

public concreteClass extends abstractClass
{
    @Override
    public int getId(){return 1;}
}
```

I used another field from the base class - flag, and it is OK, so I think the problem might be the abstract getter.
Any idea how can I use this?

Thanks

Comment: Id you map the base class as a MappedSuperclass?  It won't be picked up by JPA without it.

Comment: no, I didn't. Any way, I gave up and I added implementation to the abstract getter that won't be in use, but will be overriden always in derived classes.